# https://api.openai.com dosent be blocked by cors in content-script.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, openai-api, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i've tried fetch request such as https://slack.com/XXX or https://gateway.ai.cloudflare.com/XXX in content-script.js but they all got blocked CORS Error, except https://api.openai.com, even if i change my computer or network, can someone tell me why and what's the solution , thx ~

[image]
[image]
[image]

how can i fetch the urls except "https://api.openai.com" in content-script.js and won't blocked by CORS Error

Comment: CORS is *controlled* by the server - so, there is no *fix* other than not using your browser to request resources not allowed by CORS - however, in the case of chrome extensions, I think there's something you can do in the manifest

Comment: If you are using an extension you can modify and remove headers of the network request and response. Looks like you are getting a 401 status code in the response header.